# Etymology of "Есть!" (military command)

Tags: словоупотребление, этимология, phrase

Can it be explained how the phrase *Есть!* came to be used in the military when someone accepts an order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some search showed that it might be derived from English "yes". From [Этимологический словарь Фасмера](http://vasmer.narod.ru/p196.htm):

> Слово: есть
>
> Ближайшая этимология: II. "слушаю(сь)", воен. Из англ. yes "да, есть", сближенного по народн. этимологии с есть I; см. Томсон 347.

Comment: `Из англ. yes` "Yes, sir" to be more exact.

Comment: Does this mean, it comes via the phonetic similarity?

Comment: @MartinPeters yep

Comment: @Martin Peters modern military doesn't use "Есть", must use "Так точно!"  и "Никак нет!" there are several jokes why exactly that negative answer must be in form of double negative

Answer (score 9):

Here's a snippet from an [article](http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/quiz/690/) titled "Почему российские военные отвечают на приказ «Есть!»?":

> Петр I отрядил на корабли солдат из «потешного войска», а для их
>   обучения наняли англичан с торговых кораблей, зимовавших в
>   Архангельске. Охотников перейти на русскую службу нашлось немного —
>   всего по два человека на галеру. Русские должны были повторять все
>   действия британцев. В частности, получив приказ, отвечать: Yes, sir!
>   («Да, сэр»).

So, the article claims that dates back to the end of XVII-th century!

To be honest, though, just like @Vilmar, I've failed to find any other decent explanations, I'm very surprised. Never thought about this.

Comment: Intriguing and highly interesting!